# Implementaation Prestack Kirchhoff Time Migration in java

Tags: mapreduce

I want to implement Prestack Kirchhoff Time Migration in java and later convert the code into Map-Reduce mechanism. Can  someone give me some links for relative study or help me about how to implement this?

Comment: [How to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)